# Can a Robot Framework variable file create a dictionary that is usable in a test case?

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

I'm trying to use a robot framework variable file to create a dictionary to describe the hardware in my test bed.  Depending on the value of the argument provided, different hardware will be returned.

For example, this is the variable file that I am trying to use (named Topology.py):

```
import sys
testbed = sys.argv[1]
UUT1 = {}
UUT2 = {}

if testbed == 'development':
    UUT1 = {'platform': 'xyz', 'address': '192.168.1.1'}
    UUT2 = {'platform': 'xyz', 'address': '192.168.1.2'}
if testbed == 'production':
    UUT1 = {'platform': 'pdq', 'address': '192.168.2.1'}
    UUT2 = {'platform': 'pdq', 'address': '192.168.2.2'}
```

My goal is then to be able to reference this dictionary from within a test case. For example:

```
| | Verify Unit Is Online | ${UUT1[address]}
```

The problem I am facing is that whenever I invoke the variable file, robot immediately exits with the following error:

```
[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.
```

Is it possible to use a dictionary in this manner?

Comment: I have literally no idea what your actual question is.

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a variable file can create a dictionary. The robot framework user's guide [gives an example](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax).

You are using the wrong syntax when referencing the value. When using [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) you have to use python quoting inside the curly braces because everything inside the curly braces is treated like a python expression. The variable reference should be `${UUT1["address"]}`

Your code could also fail if `sys.argv[1]` is neither `"development"` nor `"platform"`, in which case `UUT1` and `UUT2` will not be defined.

All of that being said, will probably not cause the error `[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.` If you use the wrong syntax you'll get a different error, so the error in your question seems to be related to a different problem.